# A couple of questions about calling methods outside of QThread from within the QThread - is my design flawed?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt

I have an application that has a GUI thread and many different worker threads. In this application, I have a `functions.py` module, which contains a lot of different "utility" functions that are used all over the application.

Yesterday the application has been released and some users (a minority, but still) has reported problems with the application crashing. I looked over my code and noticed a possible design flaw, and would like to check with the lovely people of SO and see if I am right and if this is indeed a flaw.

Suppose I have this defined in my `functions.py` module:

```
class Functions:

    solveComputationSignal = Signal(str)
    updateStatusSignal = Signal(int, str)
    text = None

    @classmethod
    def setResultText(self, text):
        self.text = text

    @classmethod
    def solveComputation(cls, platform, computation, param=None):
        #Not the entirety of the method is listed here       
        result = urllib.urlopen(COMPUTATION_URL).read()
        if param is None:
            cls.solveComputationSignal.emit(result)
        else:
            cls.solveAlternateComputation(platform, computation)

        while not self.text:
            time.sleep(3)

        return self.text if self.text else False



    @classmethod
    def updateCurrentStatus(cls, platform, statusText):
        cls.updateStatusSignal.emit(platform, statusText)
```

I think these methods in themselves are fine. The two signals defined here are connected to in the GUI thread. The first signal pops-up a dialog in which the computation is presented.  The GUI thread calls the `setResultText()` method and sets the resulting string as entered by the user (if anyone knows of a better way to wait until the user has inputted the text other than sleeping and waiting for `self.text` to become True, please let me know). The `solveAlternateComputation` is another method in the same class that solves the computation automatically, however, it too calls the `setResultText()` method that sets the resulting text.

The second signal updates the statusBar text of the main GUI as well.

What's worse is that I think the above design, while perhaps flawed, is not the problem.

The problem lies, I believe, in the way I call these methods, whihch is from the worker threads (note that I have multiple similar workers, all of which are different "platforms")

Assume I have this (and I do):

```
class WorkerPlatform1(QThread):

    #Init and other methods are here

    def run(self):

        #Thread does its job here, but then when it needs to present the  
        #computation, instead of emitting a signal, this is what I do

        self.f = functions.Functions

        result = self.f.solveComputation(platform, computation)

        if result:
            #Go on with the task
        else:
            self.f.updateCurrentStatus(platform, "Error grabbing computation!")
```

In this case I think that my flaw is that the thread itself is not emitting any signals, but rather calling callables residing outside of that thread directly. Am I right in thinking that this could cause my application to crash? Although the faulty module is reported as QtGui4.dll

One more thing: both of these methods in the `Functions` class are accessed by many threads almost simultaneously. Is this even advisable - have methods residing outside of a thread be accessed by many threads all at the same time? Can it so happen that I "confuse" my program? The reason I am asking is because people who say that the application is not crashing report that, very often, the `solveComputation()` returns the incorrect text - not all the time, but very often. Since that `COMPUTATION_URL`'s server can take some time to respond (even 10+ seconds), is it possible that, once a thread calls that method, while the `urllib` library is still waiting for server response, in that time another thread can call it, causing it to use a different `COMPUTATION_URL`, which will result in it returning an incorrect value on some cases?

Finally, I am thinking of solutions: for my first (crashing) problem, do you think the proper solution would be to directly emit a `Signal` from the thread itself, and then connect it in the GUI thread? Is that the right way to go about it?

Secondly, for the `solveComputation` returning incorrect values, would I solve it by moving that method (and accompanying methods) to every `Worker` class? then I could call them directly and hopefully have the correct response - or, dozens of different responses (since I have that many threads) - for every thread?

Thank you all and I apologize for the wall of text.

**EDIT**: I would like to add that when running in console with some users, this error appears `QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QLabel(0x4795500), parent's thread is QThread(0x2d3fd90), current thread is WordpressCreator(0x49f0548)`

Comment: You are using a classmethod with class attributes to store results, and sharing that class amongst threads? I can see a number of things that could be improved.

Comment: Yes. I know it can be improved, but would you care to elaborate how? What is a better way to go about it?

Comment: If your `Functions` class needs to store results as members, dont use classmethods. Make them all normal methods and set up your instance attributes in an `__init__`, otherwise every worker than shares this will corrupt eachothers results

Comment: And for your **EDIT**, what are you doing with the `QLabel` in your thread. Are you creating them?

Comment: I have fixed the EDIT - had no idea that if a QThread calls the `sys.excepthook` (or any other method for that matter), it will call it in the context of that thread, and not in the thread in which it was defined (which was the main GUI thread).

Comment: Ya just emit signals from your thread to communicate. They will be queued in thr eventloop and called under the main thread if they target a receiver in the main thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is flawed if you really are using your `Functions` class like this with classmethods storing results on class attributes, being shared amongst multiple workers. It should be using all instance methods, and each thread should be using an instance of this class:

```
class Functions(QObject):

    solveComputationSignal = pyqtSignal(str)
    updateStatusSignal = pyqtSignal(int, str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Functions, self).__init__(parent)
        self.text = ""

    def setResultText(self, text):
        self.text = text


    def solveComputation(self, platform, computation, param=None):
        result = urllib.urlopen(COMPUTATION_URL).read()
        if param is None:
            self.solveComputationSignal.emit(result)
        else:
            self.solveAlternateComputation(platform, computation)

        while not self.text:
            time.sleep(3)

        return self.text if self.text else False


    def updateCurrentStatus(self, platform, statusText):
        self.updateStatusSignal.emit(platform, statusText)


# worker_A
    def run(self):
        ...
        f = Functions()
# worker_B
    def run(self):
        ...
        f = Functions()
```

Also, for doing your `urlopen`, instead of doing sleeps to check for when it is ready, you can make use of the [`QNetworkAccessManager`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) to make your requests and use signals to be notified when results are ready.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So this may be the cause why there are so many incorrect computations reported, because the class variable is overwritten - I hadn't thought of that. My `Functions` class has many other classmethods there that I can't get rid off, therefore I guess it's time to create a new class, specifically for these computations.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with class methods. And you can still call them from instance methods with self. The point is to realize when data is being shared. Class methods are for those that dont need unique instances to operate. They dont require shared state.